# Retrieve Data that do not exist in the primary table, exist in the secondary only

Tags: sql, sql-server

Problem:
I would like to retrieve the value that do not exist in the list table b but it exist in table a.

I don't know how to do it.

Please remember that the data will change very often.

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
      ,[email]
      ,[phone]
      ,[cellphone]
      ,[none]
  FROM [test].[dbo].[datatable]

SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
      ,[email]
      ,[phone]
      ,[cellphone]
      ,[none]
  FROM [test].[dbo].[datatable2]
```

[image]

Comment: What would be your expected result?

Comment: Your data is interesting, why is it repeating the values productname, cost and active in the NAME field. Is it just for test, dummy data? Or do these 3 rows define a valid record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT OUTER join` on the tables:
Please find the sample query below:

```
select a.* 
from tableA a
Left outer join TableB b
on a.id=b.id
where b.id is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to see if the entire row matches, you can use EXCEPT to find the result set.

```sql
SELECT [id],
    [name],
    [email],
    [phone],
    [cellphone],
    [none]
FROM [test].[dbo].[datatable]
EXCEPT
SELECT [id],
    [name],
    [email],
    [phone],
    [cellphone],
    [none]
FROM [test].[dbo].[datatable2]
```

If you're only worried about the key, I like using NOT EXISTS to get the result set.

```sql
SELECT [id],
    [name],
    [email],
    [phone],
    [cellphone],
    [none]
FROM [test].[dbo].[datatable] t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [test].[dbo].[datatable2] t2 WHERE t2.[id] = t1.[id])
```